# Cannot resolve symbol "R" (Error inflating class fragment )

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, androidx, android-studio-4.2

It is causing me unable to inflate fragment. This is from the androidx library that cannot resolve symbol "R". I have tried clean, rebuild and even invalidate and restart. Also add in this specific dependency in gradle file and also deleted the gradle cache file to let it redownload when restart. It never get to fixed

[Problem shown when at GragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YSan.png)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wayneyong.poibrowser, PID: 5527
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wayneyong.poibrowser/com.wayneyong.poibrowser.PoiBrowserActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121 in com.wayneyong.poibrowser:layout/activity_poi_browser: Binary XML file line #121 in com.wayneyong.poibrowser:layout/activity_poi_browser: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121 in com.wayneyong.poibrowser:layout/activity_poi_browser: Binary XML file line #121 in com.wayneyong.poibrowser:layout/activity_poi_browser: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121 in com.wayneyong.poibrowser:layout/activity_poi_browser: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference
        at com.wayneyong.poibrowser.ar.ArFragmentSupport.createCameraView(ArFragmentSupport.java:139)
        at com.wayneyong.poibrowser.ar.ArFragmentSupport.init(ArFragmentSupport.java:94)
        at com.wayneyong.poibrowser.ar.ArFragmentSupport.onCreateView(ArFragmentSupport.java:182)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:386)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at com.wayneyong.poibrowser.databinding.ActivityPoiBrowserBinding.inflate(ActivityPoiBrowserBinding.java:113)
        at com.wayneyong.poibrowser.databinding.ActivityPoiBrowserBinding.inflate(ActivityPoiBrowserBinding.java:107)
        at com.wayneyong.poibrowser.PoiBrowserActivity.onCreate(PoiBrowserActivity.java:122)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7894)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7881)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5527 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please check line number 121 of your  XML layout file, this is main cause of error

Comment: Remove `import androidx.fragment.R;`  and try to import R again